# Drag Fabric.js object from one canvas to another

Tags: canvas, drag-and-drop, fabricjs

I am using Fabric.js to create design on any product. my some product has two canvas so I want to move `fabric.Text` from one canvas to another and I want to drag and drop Fabric canvas object to other Fabric canvases.

Comment: answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310843/how-to-drag-and-drop-between-canvases-in-fabric-js/54600935#54600935

Answer (score 5):

I have absolutely no idea whether this is a good, bad or ugly way of doing things however I've put together a simple fiddle which achieves what you are after - the basic principle of what i've done is this:

encapsulate your canvas objects within an object, where the canvas id's are the object keys, for example

```
var canvases = {
    canvas1 : new fabric.Canvas('canvas1'),
    canvas2 : new fabric.Canvas('canvas2')
 }
```

this allows you to reference them easily later on.

Then on the canvas `mouse:down` event, if there is an active object capture a reference to it along with the id of the canvas (using `activeObject = this.getActiveObject();` and `this.lowerCanvasEl.id` respectively within the `mouse:down` callback.

note: you could use the `object:selected` event in place of `mouse:down`, however if you drag an already selected object on the canvas, it doesn't fire.

Then I bound a callback to the document `mouseup` event using jQuery `on` - the purpose of the callback is to first detect whether the target is a canvas element, if it is we get the id of your fabric canvas, compare it to the id that we stored on the `mouse:down` event earlier, and if they are different add the activeObject that we stored earlier to the new canvas target like so `canvases[canvasId].add(activeObject);` at the end of the mouseup callback I clear the activeObject and initialCanvas variables - this prevents the user from simply clicking a canvas object and then clicking on the new canvas and simulates a seamless drag-and-drop.

full code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/uppzL/12/

I hope that it's helpful, i'm sure it needs refining and improving though, especially getting the object from canvas1 to snap back to it's original starting place or disappear completely, rather than just being stuck out of the viewport of the canvas.

Comment: ThanQ, this is help for me but when i move object to other canvas then it hide inside canvas. i dont want to hide my object when i move. please help me

Comment: after the object is dragged, when the mouseup event fires you can simply reset the top and left properties of the  activeObject from canvas A (the canvas you are dragging from) and it will snap back to whatever position you would like - i've done a quick update to make it snap back to `left: 0` and `top: 0`  - here's the fiddle for it, i've commented above the two lines which update the position - hope it helps! http://jsfiddle.net/uppzL/14/

Comment: can you add a fiddle that shows the text during the whole drag, and drop according to the top left corner's position?  With your 14th example, you can't see the text when you're over the blue canvas until it snaps to {0,0}, and it would be huge if the text box would stay exactly where the mouseup event takes place...to be a bit more clear.  Very helpful, Keir!