# How to drag and drop between canvases in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I understand Fabric.js have built-in support on drag-n-drop within the same canvas.

How can we make it work for multiple canvas?

Or from an non-canvas html element e.g. an image from a table?

Comment: There is no built-in support. You'll have to write your own code, and it's not straight-forward at all. Certainly not something that can be answered here.

Comment: Hi. You need something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/ptCoder/aaFe7/9/

Comment: Other example: http://jsfiddle.net/uppzL/14/
Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311625/drag-fabric-js-object-from-one-canvas-to-another

Comment: @ptCoder it seems like the jsfiddle link you referenced has errors in IE11 at least.  Do you have another link that drags from canvas to canvas and drops in the exact spot the mouseup takes place?

Answer (score 5):

Drag and drop between canvases is possible in Fabric.js, but involves some manipulation of private properties. For this reason *it is not guaranteed to be functional with future versions of Fabric.js*.

**Working demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/kdbu9f3y/

**Video capture:** https://youtu.be/nXZgCmIrpqQ

[image: drag and drop between canvases in fabric.js]

**Key features:**

✓ can drag and drop between any number of canvases (not only two),

✓ can drag back and forth between canvases without interruption,

✓ can transform (mirror) dropped image without interruption of manipulation.

---

**Step 1** – prepare canvases, load images, arrange everything for demo:

```js
    //create two canvases
    var canvas0El = document.getElementById("c0");
    canvas0El.width = canvas0El.offsetWidth;
    canvas0El.height = canvas0El.parentElement.offsetHeight;

    var canvas1El = document.getElementById("c1");
    canvas1El.width = canvas1El.offsetWidth;
    canvas1El.height = canvas1El.parentElement.offsetHeight;

    var canvas0 = new fabric.Canvas('c0');
    canvas0.setBackgroundColor('rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.25)');
    canvas0.renderAll();

    var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
    canvas1.setBackgroundColor('rgba(92, 18, 18, 0.25)');
    canvas1.renderAll();

    // add loaded image on left canvas
    var onImageLoaded = function(oImg) {
        oImg.originX = "center";
        oImg.originY = "center";

        oImg.left = this.x;
        oImg.top = this.y;

        canvas0.add(oImg);
        oImg.canvas = canvas0;
        imgArrow = oImg;
    };

    var config = { crossOrigin: 'anonymous' };

    var baseUrl = "http://mbnsay.com/rayys/images";
    var url0 = baseUrl + "/arrow-right-green.png";
    var url1 = baseUrl + "/arrow-right-icon.png";
    var url2 = baseUrl + "/arrow-right-blue.png";

    // load some images
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url0, onImageLoaded.bind({ x: 56,  y: 96 }), config);
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url0, onImageLoaded.bind({ x: 156, y: 96 }), config);

    fabric.Image.fromURL(url1, onImageLoaded.bind({ x: 56,  y: 2*96 }), config);
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url1, onImageLoaded.bind({ x: 156, y: 2*96 }), config);

    fabric.Image.fromURL(url2, onImageLoaded.bind({ x: 56,  y: 3*96 }), config);
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url2, onImageLoaded.bind({ x: 156, y: 3*96 }), config);
```

**Step 2** – subscribe `object:moving` events on both canvases, and watch when object center crossing the canvas border. When object crosses the border, it has to be

1. remove from source canvas,
2. paste into destination canvas,
3. migrate internal canvas transformations (will be explained separately)

```js
    var onObjectMoving = function(p) {
        var viewport = p.target.canvas.calcViewportBoundaries();

        if (p.target.canvas === canvas0) {
            if (p.target.left > viewport.br.x) {
                console.log("Migrate: left -> center");
                migrateItem(canvas0, canvas1, p.target);
                return;
            }
        }
        if (p.target.canvas === canvas1) {
            if (p.target.left < viewport.tl.x) {
                console.log("Migrate: center -> left");
                migrateItem(canvas1, canvas0, p.target);
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    canvas0.on("object:moving", onObjectMoving);
    canvas1.on("object:moving", onObjectMoving);
```

**Step 3** – The core of the solution, migrate object between canvases not interrupting mouse manipulations. Hard to explain, just follow the comments in code.

```
    var migrateItem = function(fromCanvas, toCanvas, pendingImage) {
        // Just drop image from old canvas
        fromCanvas.remove(pendingImage);

        // We're going to trick fabric.js,
        // so we keep internal transforms of the source canvas, 
        // in order to inject it into destination canvas.
        var pendingTransform = fromCanvas._currentTransform;
        fromCanvas._currentTransform = null;

        // Make shortcuts for fabric.util.removeListener and fabric.util.addListener
        var removeListener = fabric.util.removeListener;
        var addListener = fabric.util.addListener;

        // Re-arrange subscriptions for source canvas
        {
            removeListener(fabric.document, 'mouseup', fromCanvas._onMouseUp);
            removeListener(fabric.document, 'touchend', fromCanvas._onMouseUp);

            removeListener(fabric.document, 'mousemove', fromCanvas._onMouseMove);
            removeListener(fabric.document, 'touchmove', fromCanvas._onMouseMove);

            addListener(fromCanvas.upperCanvasEl, 'mousemove', fromCanvas._onMouseMove);
            addListener(fromCanvas.upperCanvasEl, 'touchmove', fromCanvas._onMouseMove, {
                passive: false
            });

            if (isTouchDevice) {
                // Wait 500ms before rebinding mousedown to prevent double triggers
                // from touch devices
                var _this = fromCanvas;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    addListener(_this.upperCanvasEl, 'mousedown', _this._onMouseDown);
                }, 500);
            }
        }

        // Re-arrange subscriptions for destination canvas
        {
            addListener(fabric.document, 'touchend', toCanvas._onMouseUp, {
                passive: false
            });
            addListener(fabric.document, 'touchmove', toCanvas._onMouseMove, {
                passive: false
            });

            removeListener(toCanvas.upperCanvasEl, 'mousemove', toCanvas._onMouseMove);
            removeListener(toCanvas.upperCanvasEl, 'touchmove', toCanvas._onMouseMove);

            if (isTouchDevice) {
                // Unbind mousedown to prevent double triggers from touch devices
                removeListener(toCanvas.upperCanvasEl, 'mousedown', toCanvas._onMouseDown);
            } else {
                addListener(fabric.document, 'mouseup', toCanvas._onMouseUp);
                addListener(fabric.document, 'mousemove', toCanvas._onMouseMove);
            }
        }

        // We need this timer, because we want Fabric.js to complete pending render
        // before we inject, because it causes some unpleasant image jumping.
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Add image to destination canvas,
            pendingImage.scaleX *= -1;
            pendingImage.canvas = toCanvas;
            pendingImage.migrated = true;
            toCanvas.add(pendingImage);

            // and inject transforms from source canvas
            toCanvas._currentTransform = pendingTransform;

            // as we have mirrored the image, we mirror transforms too
            toCanvas._currentTransform.scaleX *= -1;
            toCanvas._currentTransform.original.scaleX *= -1;

            // finally don't forget to make pasted object selected
            toCanvas.setActiveObject(pendingImage);
        }, 10);
    };
```

Have fun!

Comment: You said it will work for multiple canvases but you have applied hardcoded canvas while migrating data from one place to other. Can you help me a little bit here?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 canvas.observe("object:moving", function (event) {});
```

If event.e.clientY and event.e.clientX are outside the canvas, then:

```
var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
```

Store in global dragImage var

```
activeObject.clone(function (c) { dragImage = c; });

canvas.remove(activeObject);
```

Then in window mouse move event you can place an img with src = dragImage.src and follow the cursor.

```
function mousemove(e){
if (dragImage != null) {
    $("#dragimage").show();
    $("#dragimage").css("left", e.clientX); 
    $("#dragimage").css("top", e.clientY);
    return;
}else{
$("#dragimage").hide();
}
}
```

On a window event mouseup, if dragImage != null and new coordinates are inside a fabric.js canvas, just newcanvas.add(dragImage).

mouseup event:

```
if (dragImage != null) {
            $([canvas, canvas2]).each(function (i, v) {
                if (Intersect([event.clientX, event.clientY],$(v.wrapperEl))) {
                    dragImage.left = event.clientX - $(v.wrapperEl).offset().left;
                    dragImage.top = event.clientY - $(v.wrapperEl).offset().top;
                    v.add(dragImage);
                }              

            });

            dragImage = null;
        }
```

Helper Intersect function:

```
function Intersect(point, element) {
    return (      point[0] > element.offset().left
               && point[0] < element.offset().left + element.width()
               && point[1] < element.offset().top + element.height()
               && point[1] > element.offset().top
            );    
}
```

css for #dragimage:

```
#dragimage
{
    opacity:0.5;
    max-width:100px;
    max-height:200px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:90000;
}
```

I can't do a fiddle but i implemented this on our mega huge photo album editor in less than 30 minutes. Works for text too but for text you must use dragImage=getActiveObject().clone()
Any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: any chance for a fiddle on this? Drag and drop between two faric canvasas? TX Sean